# android opengl check visibility of a point with camera zoom

Tags: android, opengl-es, camera, 2d, visibility

I m woring on an android opengl 1.1 2d game with a top view on a vehicule and a camera zoom relative to the vehicule speed. When the speed increases the camera zoom out to offer the player a best road visibility.

I have litte trouble finding the exact way to detect if a sprite is visible or not regarding his position and the current camera zoom.

Important precision, all of my game's objects are on the same z coord. I use 3d just for camera effect. (that's why I do not need frustrum complicated calculations)

here is a sample of my GLSurfaceView.Renderer class

```
public static float fov_degrees =  45f;
public static float fov_radians =  fov_degrees / 180 * (float) Math.PI;
public static float aspect; //1.15572 on my device
public static float camZ;  //927 on my device



@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int x, int y) {

    aspect =  (float) x / (float) y;
    camZ = y / 2 / (float) Math.tan(fov_radians / 2);

    Camera.MINIDECAL = y / 4;   // minimum cam zoom out (192 on my device)

    if (x == 0) { // Prevent A Divide By Zero By
        x = 1; // Making Height Equal One
    }
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, x, y); // Reset The Current Viewport
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION); // Select The Projection Matrix
    gl.glLoadIdentity(); // Reset The Projection Matrix

    // Calculate The Aspect Ratio Of The Window
    GLU.gluPerspective(gl, fov_degrees, aspect , camZ / 10, camZ * 10);

    GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0, 0, camZ, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0); // move camera back


    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW); // Select The Modelview Matrix

    gl.glLoadIdentity(); // Reset The Modelview Matrix
```

when I draw any camera relative object I use this translation method :

```
gl.glTranslatef(position.x - camera.centerPosition.x , position.y -camera.centerPosition.y , - camera.zDecal);
```

Eveything is displayed fine, the problem comes from my physic thread when he checks if an object is visible or not:

```
public static boolean isElementVisible(Element element) {

    xDelta =  (float) ((camera.zDecal + GameRenderer.camZ) * GameRenderer.aspect *  Math.atan(GameRenderer.fov_radians));
    yDelta = (float) ((camera.zDecal + GameRenderer.camZ)*   Math.atan(GameRenderer.fov_radians));

    //(xDelta and yDelta are in reallity updated only ones a frame or when camera zoom change)

    Camera camera = ObjectRegistry.INSTANCE.camera;

    float xMin = camera.centerPosition.x - xDelta/2;
    float xMax = camera.centerPosition.x + xDelta/2;

    float yMin = camera.centerPosition.y - yDelta/2;
    float yMax = camera.centerPosition.y + yDelta/2;

    //xMin and yMin are supposed to be the lower bounds x and y of the visible plan
    // same for yMax and xMax

    // then i just check that my sprite is visible on this rectangle.


    Vector2 phD = element.getDimToTestIfVisibleOnScreen();
    int sizeXd2 = (int) phD.x / 2;
    int sizeYd2 = (int) phD.y / 2;


    return (element.position.x + sizeXd2 > xMin)
            && (element.position.x - sizeXd2 < xMax)
            && (element.position.y - sizeYd2 < yMax)
            && (element.position.y + sizeYd2 > yMin);


}
```

Unfortunately the object were disapearing too soon and appearing to late so i manuelly added some zoom out on the camera for test purpose.

I did some manual test and found that by adding approx 260 to the camera z index while calculating xDelta and yDelta it, was good.
So the line is now :

```
xDelta =  (float) ((camera.zDecal + GameRenderer.camZ + 260) * GameRenderer.aspect *  Math.atan(GameRenderer.fov_radians));
yDelta = (float) ((camera.zDecal + GameRenderer.camZ + 260)*   Math.atan(GameRenderer.fov_radians));
```

Because it's a hack and the magic number may not work on every device I would like to understand what i missed. I guess there is something in that "260" magic number that comes from the fov or ration width/height and that could be set as a formula parameter for pixel perfect detection.

Any guess ?

Comment: What happens if you use Math.tan(GameRenderer.fov_radians) instead of atan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you should be using `Math.tan(GameRenderer.fov_radians)` instead of `Math.atan(GameRenderer.fov_radians)`.

Reasoning:

If you used a camera with 90 degree fov, then `xDelta` and `yDelta` should be infinitely large, right? Since the camera would have to view the entire infinite plane.

tan(pi/2) is infinite (and negative infinity). atan(pi/2) is merely 1.00388...

tan(pi/4) is 1, compared to atan(pi/4) of 0.66577...

Comment: And it works ! Thank a lot Patashu you just won a free copy of my future game ;)